# Как сделать ,чтобы нарисованные фигуры в HTML5 canvas, двигались с разной скоростью?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Всем Привет!
Как мне сделать, чтобы нарисованные фигуры (два квадрата),
двигались - первый медленней, второй быстрее. (*код ниже*)
Заранее СПАСИБО за уделенное время!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
     html, body {padding: 0;margin: 0;}
     * {box-sizing: border-box;}
     body {background: #ddd;
     }
     #mc{
      display: block;
      background: #000;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "mc"></canvas>
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var
       canv                 = document.getElementById('mc'), // canvas
       ctx                  = canv.getContext('2d'); // 2d context

       canv.width = window.innerWidth;
       canv.height = window.innerHeight;
  
       var x = 0;
       var y = 100;

       setInterval(
         function () { 
           ctx.fillStyle = "white";
           ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

           ctx.fillStyle = "magenta";
           ctx.fillRect(x++, 0, 100, 100);

           if(x > canv.width){
             x = 0;
           }
          
           ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
           ctx.fillRect(y++, 250, 100, 100);

           if(y > canv.width){
              y = 0;
            } 
          }, 3
       );

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: менять координаты на разные величины...

Comment: Но изменится только положение, нужно изменить скорость для каждой из фигур

Comment: Ваша анимация это изменение положение в цикле, вот положение надо менять на разные значения для разных объектов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде координаты x, y в каждой итерации меняются на одинаковую величину - на 1 единицу (x++, y++) сделайте x++, y+=2 и y будет меняться вдвое быстрей, значит и соответствующий квадрат будет двигаться быстрей:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
     html, body {padding: 0;margin: 0;}
     * {box-sizing: border-box;}
     body {background: #ddd;
     }
     #mc{
      display: block;
      background: #000;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id = "mc"></canvas>
</body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var
       canv                 = document.getElementById('mc'), // canvas
       ctx                  = canv.getContext('2d'); // 2d context

       canv.width = window.innerWidth;
       canv.height = window.innerHeight;
  
       var x = 0;
       var y = 100;

       setInterval(
         function () { 
           ctx.fillStyle = "white";
           ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

           ctx.fillStyle = "magenta";
           ctx.fillRect(x++, 0, 100, 100);

           if(x > canv.width){
             x = 0;
           }
          
           ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
           ctx.fillRect(y+=2, 120, 100, 100);

           if(y > canv.width){
              y = 0;
            } 
          }, 3
       );

    </script>
</html>
```